# Packages without source cannot generate msgs?

Tags: ros, catkin, cmake, message-generation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I put several custom defined msgs in a package (named custom_msg_pkg), and this package does not contain any cpp or python sources. Then I have other packages depending on this package, using the provided custom msgs. But at compilation time (through catkin_make), the custom_msg_pkg is not being built first, so the compiler gives errors complaining not able to find the custom defined msgs in the custom_msg_pkg.

I am quite sure that I don't get it wrong in package.xml or CMakeLists.txt, since if I manually build them one by one, it works. So I think the problem lies in the order of building packages. In the custom_msg_pkg's CMakeLists.txt, I cannot add `add_dependencies(executable custom_msg_pkg_generate_messages_cpp)`, so these messages are not built in the first place when I simple strike `catkin_make`.

So I am writing to ask:

1. If there is some way to make the custom_msg_pkg built before the dependent packages?
2. Is it a bad idea to have a package without source but only contains msg/srv files?

Thanks for any suggestions!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172256/packages-without-source-cannot-generate-msgs?/) by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 391 on 2014-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. It looks like you have most of your packages set up correctly, however you should be putting the `add_dependencies` line in the CMakeLists.txt for your other packages, NOT in your custom_msg_pkg. This allows you to explicitly declare that a particular binary in a dependant package depends on the generation of your custom messages.
2. Yes; a package that contains only messages is fine, and it is the recommended practice for large projects.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on 2014-06-02**:
Thanks for pointing out! It's indeed the problem.